# Exception while reading a parquet file from S3 on local PySpark using s3a protocol

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a simple code below to read a parquet file from S3 using S3a

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import configparser

# os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell"

# Get the AWS credentials for the mlandexps profile using configparser library

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/credentials"))

access_key = config.get("mlandexps", "aws_access_key_id")
secret_key = config.get("mlandexps", "aws_secret_access_key")

print("Access Key : %s" % access_key)
print("Secret Key : %s" % secret_key)

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("ReadFilesFromS3TestUsingS3a") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");


df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://rppatwa/BlackWidowData/part-00000-5b22d5ed-2be1-4343-9aa2-53e2133916ae-c000.snappy.parquet")
df.printSchema()
df.show(3)
```

I get the following exception when I run it locally

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-17-ffd16a1a558f> in <module>
     37 print("Spark Context : {}".format(sc))
     38 
---> 39 df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://rppatwa/BlackWidowData/part-00000-5b22d5ed-2be1-4343-9aa2-53e2133916ae-c000.snappy.parquet")
     40 df.printSchema()
     41 df.show(3)

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in parquet(self, *paths)
    314         [('name', 'string'), ('year', 'int'), ('month', 'int'), ('day', 'int')]
    315         """
--> 316         return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
    317 
    318     @ignore_unicode_prefix

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~/Downloads/Spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o514.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.19.237:62286
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply$mcV$sp(NettyRpcEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:816)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:808)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:808)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1402)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation timed out: /192.168.19.237:62286
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.mergeSchemasInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:633)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.inferSchema(ParquetFileFormat.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$6.apply(DataSource.scala:180)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.19.237:62286
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply$mcV$sp(NettyRpcEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$openChannel$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:693)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:816)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:808)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:808)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1402)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation timed out: /192.168.19.237:62286
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:688)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am guessing the root cause of this exception has something to do with this line

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.19.237:62286

I've looked around the web and haven't found a very useful answer. Appreciate your points!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe add `hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")` ?

Comment: @mazaneicha That worked! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @ram-ghadiyaram NPEs do happen for all different kinds of reasons :)  Rahul Patwa, glad it worked out.